# Print details from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-science, data-analysis, dictionary-comprehension

```
SM={'Technician A':{'Ticket ID':1,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 1','status':'Delivered'},
      'Technician B':{'Ticket ID':2,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 3','status':'WIP'},
      'Technician C':{'Ticket ID':3,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 2','status':'WIP'},
      'Technician D':{'Ticket ID':4,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 7','status':'Delivered'},
     'Technician E':{'Ticket ID':5,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 8','status':'Delivered'},
     'Technician F':{'Ticket ID':6,'Start date':'14-03-2020','End date':'25-03-2020',' location':'Area 9','status':'Delivered'}}
```

From SM dictionary I want to Print all details where the status is WIP with Technician Name which is Technician A, Technician B...…

I have tried below code but not getting technician name:

```
for e1 in SM:
    if SM[e1]['status']=='WIP':
         print(SM[e1])
```

Please advice me what's wrong with the code above, or any alternative way to get the result I want - to fetch Technician name from SM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, e1 is the technician name.

So, your code can go like this :

```
for e1 in SM: 
    if SM[e1]['status']=='WIP': 
        print(SM[e1])
        print(e1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for e1 in SM:
    if SM[e1]['status']=='WIP':
        print(e1)
```

SM[e1] would return the value. Technician is the key.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Here, key and values are keys and values of the dictionary respectively.

```
for key, values in SM.items():
    if SM[key]['status'] == 'WIP':
        print(key)
```